# How prove this inequality $\frac{e^x}{x+1}>\frac{\cos{x}}{\sin{x}+\sqrt{2}}$

Tags: inequality

Today,when I use [wolf](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5Ex%2F%28x%2B1%29-cosx%2F%28sinx%2Bsqrt%282%29%29) found this following inequality

> let $x>-1$, show that
>   $$\dfrac{e^x}{x+1}>\dfrac{\cos{x}}{\sin{x}+\sqrt{2}}$$

I found this [image]

I want $$\Longleftrightarrow (\sin{x}+\sqrt{2})e^x-(x+1)\cos{x}>0$$
let
$$f(x)=(\sin{x}+\sqrt{2})e^x-(x+1)\cos{x}\Longrightarrow f'(x)=\sqrt{2}e^x+(x+e^x+1)\sin{x}+(e^x-1)\cos{x}$$
then I calculus $f''(x)$ and found ugly,so maybe this inequality have other methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it just follows from:
$$\left|\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{2}+\sin x}\right|\leq 1\tag{1}$$
and:
$$\frac{e^x}{x+1}\geq 1.\tag{2}$$
$(1)$ is equivalent to:
$$ \cos^2 x\leq 2+\sin^2 x+2\sqrt{2}\sin x \tag{3}$$
or to:
$$ 1+2\sin^2 x+2\sqrt{2}\sin x \geq 0 \tag{4}$$
that is trivial since the discriminant of $2y^2+2\sqrt{2}y+1$ is zero. On the other hand,
$$ e^x \geq 1+x \tag{5} $$
is a trivial inequality, too.

Answer (score 5):

We know $\sqrt{2}+\sin x > 0$ since $|\sin x| \le 1$ and $\sqrt{2} > 1$.

$\displaystyle \frac{e^{x}}{x+1} \ge 1 \ge \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{2}+\sin x}$, the later inequality is true since,

$1 \ge \sin (\frac{\pi}{4} - x) = \dfrac{\cos x - \sin x}{\sqrt{2}}$